# p:chart change displayed numbers

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot

I want to change the displaying number of my chart. As you can see i the picture below, primefaces chart sums the numbers and displays the sum at the end of the bar.

[image]

But i dont want him to sum. I just want to see the actual number of the bar. When i sys.out the values in my java code he is actually printing the real number and not the sum. Does someone know how i can change it?

Comment: check the jQPlot documentation. Most likely something in there

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you can do that with jqPlot plugin. You need to write JS function where you define your needs (PF uses jqPlot charts but not all functionality are supported, so you need to write it with JS using jqPlot).

for example:

charts.js

```
function barChart(){
   this.cfg.legend = {
      show: true,
      location: 'ne'
   };

   this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
      pointLabels: {
         show: true,
         formatString: '%d'
      }
   };
}
```

ClassNameBean.java

```
...
//call your JS function
chartName.setExtender("barChart");
...
```

Check jqPlot documentation [jQPlot barChart Examples](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/barTest.php#), to add more attributes to your JS function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that i have to write a JS function, but i cant find in the documentation where to change this logic.